# Copy SSRS reports to another server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, ssrs, ssrs-2014

I am new to SSRS and I have been tasked to copy the SSRS reports(from PROD) to another Server(QA).

I found many  documentations that show how to migrate the reports by Restoring ReportServer, ReportServerTempDB and encryption key.

I just want to confirm. After doing above, my main environment(prod) will remain intact and operational?Please confirm. I'm creating a QA environment that I am copying from PROD and I cannot afford for anything to happen to PROD.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft makes a reporting migration tool.
[Reporting Services Migration Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29560) .

One drawback is that the Target server must be SharePoint integrated mode.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, doing that method you describe (I have done it myself) will leave your source environment fully operational and without issue.  Any subscriptions you have in the source environment won't fully copy over unless you *also* copy the Agent Jobs from source to target though.  .... although that may be what you want.

And if you are going to a different environment, do you want them pointing to the production database?  You may want to just forget the encryption key stuff and leave the data sources broken if you are going to have to change them all anyways.  All that moving the encryption key over does is allow the new environment to use the saved password information.

But you may also want to take this opportunity to add all your reports into source control (Visual Studio).  Then you can just deploy from the project to whatever target server you want.  There are powershell methods around somewhere (I think DBA Tools) that can help with this, extracting all the rdl files to a folder, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the report that you want to copy and choose the Download option.  Download it to a file share and then upload it on the new site.

Comment: Thank you Paul for answer. There are hundreds of reports, data sources and I am doing this for multiple servers. This way will be too time consuming

Answer (score 0):

From this question: [SQL Reporting Services - COPY reports to another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205798/sql-reporting-services-copy-reports-to-another-folder)

I found this tool can both download and upload reports. Plus it lists out folders and subfolders on both the source and destination SSRS servers.

http://code.google.com/p/reportsync/